# Can a player kill CONCORD?

Tags: eve-online

Can a player kill CONCORD on his own?

Are their any Corporations/Fleets that have done an assault on CONCORD?

Comment: I once attacked the gate guard with a Reaper... The projectile trail was as wide as my ship. :/

Comment: Oh, *Reaper* - I thought you said *Reavers*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past this was possible -- see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnjK5EVsIfI).  A google search for "zombie siege of yulai" should turn up a lot of old discussions.

These days it is generally believed to be impossible to destroy even a single ship (the weak "concord" ships you destroy on pirate quests do not count), let alone the whole corporation!

Answer (score 4):

As a warning, even if you do (and you can't any more), it's considered an exploit and you will be banned for it.

Comment: I thought that surviving the counterattack was the exploit, not succeeding at the original attack.

Comment: Surviving the attack is an exploit, but also CCP made them nearly invincible, so killing them would be an exploit to.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: @Rushyo, I agree. This "update" was one of the weaker ones they did that, imo, messes with the whole emersion aspect of the game. If I want to attack concord, I should be able to and Concord should react by sending blobs to defeat me.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get banned for attacking or even killing a concord ship.  The concord ships are very strong and hard to kill, but if you do get one down they will send four more to replace it.